how can i config vendure and static page at nginx and simultaneously run in browser?
either one site is run the browser vendure or sataic site
hi guys i am trying to configure vendure and one static page in nginx at my local system.both vendure and static point my local IP. i want run both sites at the same time. but it did't work either only one is run another site is give a error. please help to resolve the problem.
